# php-mysqlnd failure on startup

Tags: php, centos

I found php warning in log today.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_memcache.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_memcache.so: undefined symbol: memcached_strerror in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0

Regarding php info mysqlnd is loaded but without memcached plugin.
```

> It is Centos 6.6
>
> php 5.4.42
>
> mysqlnd 5.0.10

And I do not know what to do since I can not just remove and reinstall due to some complex dependencies.Is it possible to correct it without yum remove/install to keep dependency?

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: the second problem was simple - while php modules substitions to instal mysqlnd the pdo.so was removed - so I just add it to pdo.in in /etc/php.d

Comment: make sure the dynamic libraries are in place by doing ls -lh /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_memcache.so and ls -lh /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so and added them in the php.ini file by using cat /etc/php.ini | grep 'mysqlnd_memcache.so \| pdo_mysqlnd.so'

Comment: yes, the modules there. But it seems something is missed. Anyway after all those steps 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_memcache.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_memcache.so: undefined symbol: memcached_strerror in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0

Comment: can you post output of cat /etc/php.ini | grep 'mysqlnd_memcache.so \| pdo_mysqlnd.so'

Comment: extension=mysqlnd_memcache.so

Comment: try adding this line in php.ini extension=pdo_mysqlnd.so  right after extension=mysqlnd_memcache.so and restart webserver.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_memcache.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_memcache.so: undefined symbol: memcached_strerror in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0 –

this fixes by creating file with "extension=pdo.so" in /etc/php.d/

Comment: if I add this the following warning thrown

Comment: if I add this the following warning thrown PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0